# Repeat a specific value per firm to all years

Tags: copy, stata

I have a panel data ranging from year 1917 to 1922 with various variables (for example Leverage) for 200 firms.
It looks something like this:

- Year ID Leverage

1. 1917 1  0.1
2. 1918 1  0.2
3. 1919 1  0.3
4. 1917 2  0.4
5. 1918 2  0.5
6. 1917 3  0.6
7. 1918 3  0.7
8. 1919 3  0.8
9. 1920 3  0.9
   ....

I want to copy the values for 1917 to all other years (1918, 1919,...) for the variables per FirmID. As in my example, not all years are present (so I cannot say that the value is there every X row). The result must be something like:

- Year ID Leverage

1. 1917 1  0.1
2. 1918 1  0.1
3. 1919 1  0.1
4. 1917 2  0.4
5. 1918 2  0.4
6. 1917 3  0.6
7. 1918 3  0.6
8. 1919 3  0.6
9. 1920 3  0.6
   ....

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear
input year id leverage
1917 1 0.1
1918 1 0.2
1919 1 0.3
1917 2 0.4
1918 2 0.5
1917 3 0.6
1918 3 0.7
1919 3 0.8
1920 3 0.9
end

gen leverage1917 = leverage if year == 1917

bysort id: egen min = min(leverage1917)
replace leverage = min
drop min leverage1917

. list, sepby(id)

     +----------------------+
     | year   id   leverage |
     |----------------------|
  1. | 1917    1         .1 |
  2. | 1918    1         .1 |
  3. | 1919    1         .1 |
     |----------------------|
  4. | 1917    2         .4 |
  5. | 1918    2         .4 |
     |----------------------|
  6. | 1917    3         .6 |
  7. | 1918    3         .6 |
  8. | 1919    3         .6 |
  9. | 1920    3         .6 |
     +----------------------+
```

EDIT NJC

This could be simplified to

```
generate leverage1917 = leverage if year == 1917 
bysort id (leverage1917) : replace leverage1917 = leverage1917[1]
```

thus cutting out the `egen` call and the generation of another variable you then need to `drop`. This works properly even if there is no value for 1917 for some values of `id`.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of suggesting a simplification. Feel free to use it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing @Cybernike's helpful data example, here are two ways to do it in one line

```
clear
input year id leverage
1917 1 0.1
1918 1 0.2
1919 1 0.3
1917 2 0.4
1918 2 0.5
1917 3 0.6
1918 3 0.7
1919 3 0.8
1920 3 0.9
end

egen wanted1 = mean(cond(year == 1917, leverage, .)), by(id)

egen wanted2 = mean(leverage / (year == 1917)), by(id)

list, sepby(id)

     +------------------------------------------+
     | year   id   leverage   wanted1   wanted2 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1917    1         .1        .1        .1 |
  2. | 1918    1         .2        .1        .1 |
  3. | 1919    1         .3        .1        .1 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  4. | 1917    2         .4        .4        .4 |
  5. | 1918    2         .5        .4        .4 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  6. | 1917    3         .6        .6        .6 |
  7. | 1918    3         .7        .6        .6 |
  8. | 1919    3         .8        .6        .6 |
  9. | 1920    3         .9        .6        .6 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```

For detailed discussion of both methods, see Sections 9 and 10 of [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055).

I don't overwrite the original data, contrary to your request. Often you decide later that you need them after all, or someone asks to see them.

This isn't necessarily better than the solution of @Cybernike. The division method behind `wanted2` has struck some experienced users as too tricksy, and I tend to recommend the `cond()` device behind `wanted1`.